# How to seed but do not duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, seed

Hi I want to seed my database in rails and I have Labeling model who is the junction table into Gossip model and Tag model.

I want each Gossip have at least one tag and between 1 and 3 tags.  But i won't the gossip have 2 times the same tag.

```
gossip_array = Gossip.all
​
gossip_array.each do |gossip|
    rand(1..3).times do |index|
        l = Labeling.new(gossip: gossip, tag: Tag.all.sample)
        l.save if
    end 
end
```

I think I have to put after the if a thing like : if this doesn't exist yet but i don't know how to do that or maybe its exist a better solution.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Rails 4 or later? If so, check out `#find_or_create_by`. Example (split into 2 lines to make it a little easier to read):

```
tag = Tag.all.sample
Labeling.find_or_create_by(gossip: gossip, tag: tag)
```

This will first query for a Labeling with the given `gossip` and `tag`. If such a Labeling exists, then nothing happens. But if it doesn't exist, then a new one is created with the given `gossip` and `tag`.

[Rails docs on ActiveRecord::Relation#find_or_create_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)

Comment: i use rails 5.2.4.1

Comment: Excellent. Did using `find_or_create_by` work for you?

Comment: Place it inside the `rand(1..3).times do |index|` loop

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
gossip_array = Gossip.all

gossip_array.each do |gossip|
    rand(1..3).times do |index|
        Labeling.find_or_create_by(gossip: gossip, tag: Tag.all.sample)
    end 
end
```